# Auto sort a column and auto duplicate all sheets to one sheet

Tags: google-sheets

The title speaks for itself. I am looking to do two things in Google Sheets, because I am entering data from a different third-party app using Google API.

**First**:

I need Google Sheets to auto sort a column I specify with it's rows. So for example, this:

```
   | A       | B
=====================
 1 | This is | 22
 2 | Is      | 33
 3 | A Test  | 44
```

Should look like this when sorting column A:

```
   | A       | B
=====================
 1 | A Test  | 44
 2 | Is      | 33
 3 | This is | 22
```

**Second**:

I have 7 sheets in the same workbook and they all carry the same format and data type. I want them to be automatically copied (duplicated) as is to an 8th sheet, so whenever I add any data in, for example, sheet 1, it automatically be add to the last sheet, which will be containing all the data from all the sheets in the workbook.

I hope that I am clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting a range (for example A and B columns) is a built-in function:

1. Select the range to be sorted
2. Go to Data>Sort
3. Specify sorting criteria.

---

To duplicate to another sheet, you have to first decide how wide the original ones are going to get. For example, suppose each sheet only uses five columns A:E.

Then on Sheet8 you can enter

```
A1 =ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!A:E)
G1 =ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet2!A:E)
```

and so on. This way, the content of Sheet1 is in columns A:E of Sheet8, the content of Sheet2 is in columns G:K, and so on.